# Add a new tag only on a pre-specified key combination

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events, keystroke

I want to provide tagging like feature in my text-box, following through Stackoverflow I downloaded and added http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js file in my ASP.NET web folder and I am able to use all of its function through my js function.

The problem I am suffering with is because of an event (`focusout`) in my js  code , At current I need to make an `on('focusout')` event to add a tag in my search box.
I've added HTML and CSS code also, and they are just fine, my problem is with JavaScript code
Code:
**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tags">
  <input type="text" id="search" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
#tags{
  float:left;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:5px;
  font-family:Arial;
}
#tags span.tag{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  color:#000;
  background:#eee;
  padding:5px;
  padding-right:25px;
  margin:4px;
}
#tags span.tag:hover{
  opacity:0.7;
}
#tags span.tag:after{
 position:absolute;
 content:"x";
 border:1px solid;
 padding:0 4px;
 margin:3px 0 10px 5px;
 font-size:10px;
}
#tags input{
  background:#fff;
  border:0;
  margin:4px;
  padding:7px;
  width:auto;
}
#search{
   background:#fff;
  border: 0px;
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#tags input').on('focusout',function(){    
  var txt= $.trim( $(this).val() );
  if(txt){
     $("#search").before('<span class="tag">'+txt+'</span>');
  }
  $(this).prop('value','');  
});


$('#tags').on('click','.tag',function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

**Problem:**

> I don't want my user to click outside everytime user wants to add a
> tag, I want to make it rather easier with a key combination of
> `Ctrl`+`Enter`. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `focusout` event with a `keydown` event:

```
$('#tags input').keydown(function (e) {
   if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
      var txt= $.trim( $(this).val() );
      if(txt){
         $("#search").before('<span class="tag">'+txt+'</span>');
      }
      $(this).prop('value',''); 
   }
});
```

Explanation: You check your `Event` object to see if ctrl key was pressed:

```
if(e.ctrlKey
```

And checking what was pressed at the same time (13 is the keycode for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>):

```
if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 13) {
```

If both statements are true, then you can assume your user has pressed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> combination.

**JSFiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/losnir/FxQ62/

Comment: I'd thought I'll also need Keyup event.. Okay let me try

Comment: It works great, check my JSFiddle. If you still have problems, then describe them.

Comment: I am really sorry, It was my fault I forgot to update my code with your code.... Yes... it is now working, THanks

Comment: Glad I could help, and welcome to StackOverflow! If you feel my answer was useful, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer.